# Tkinter window is not opening from thread, using data from the socket connection

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, pyautogui

I am working on the learning project similar to TeamViewer but very simple. I am establishing a connection between two PCs with socket. In each PS I am opening two threads: one thread couple is for receiving the image of the screen from one PC and displaying on the other with tkinter, the other thread couple is for sending keyboard and mouse commands from one PC to the other for performing the commands.
However, I am facing a problem that my tkinter is not opening from thread.

**Here is my code for one PC:**

```
from socket import *
import _thread as thread
import tkinter, pickle

class TeamVieverServer:
    port = 50004
    host = ''

    def __init__(self):
        conn = self.connector()
        self.dispacher(conn)

    def connector(self, port=port, host=host):
        sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.bind((host, port))
        sock.listen(5)
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print(b'Received data from the client is [%s]' % data)
        conn.send(b'Prion')
        return conn

    def dispacher(self, conn):
        thread.start_new_thread(self.recv_thread,(conn,))
        thread.start_new_thread(self.send_thread,(conn,))

    def send_thread(self, conn):
        pass

    def recv_thread(self, conn):
        screen_size = conn.recv(1024)
        width, height = pickle.loads(screen_size)
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        tkinter.Frame(root, width=width, height=height).pack()
        root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TeamVieverServer()
```

In here I am receiving some info from the other PS to open corresponding tkinter window.

**Here is my code for other PC:**

```
from socket import *
import _thread as thread
import tkinter, pickle
import pyautogui
class TeamVieverClient:
    port = 50004
    host = '***************'

    def __init__(self):
        conn = self.connector()
        self.dispacher(conn)

    def connector(self, port=port, host=host):
        sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect((host, port))
        sock.send(b'Connection is estalished')
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        print('Server:[%s]' % data)
        return sock

    def dispacher(self, conn):
        thread.start_new_thread(self.recv_thread,(conn,))
        thread.start_new_thread(self.send_thread,(conn,))

    def send_thread(self, conn):
        screen_size = pyautogui.size()
        conn.send(pickle.dumps(screen_size))

    def recv_thread(self, conn):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TeamVieverClient()
```

In here I am sending information.
The problem is that the connection is being established but the tkinter window is not opening.
Can someone help with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The tkinter window won't show until your code reaches the `mainloop()` call. You have that *after* the `recv(1024)` call, which means the window won't open until you have received 1,024 bytes of data. BTW: tkinter is well known not to work well outside of the main thread. You need to completely restructure this to start tkinter in the main thread.

Comment: Also, this is not going to work. First, Teamviewer etc don't send live video, that would be far too slow. They send updates only, aka move the cursor image 6 pixels to the right. Second, tkinter is very slow at anything animated. A monitor sized image will only be able to update a couple times per second.